# Is there a difference between the API search and the search from within the site?

Tags: discussion, api-v2, search

I'm curious if the search results from the API is calculated the same way as the searches from within the sites themselves?

Is there a difference between the two?  If so, what are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

The API only allows you to search in Questions. All four endpoints state that:

| End point | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [Search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) | Search the site for questions meeting certain criteria. |
| [search advanced](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) | Search the site for questions using most of the on-site search options. |
| [Similar](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/similar) | Search the site based on similarity to a title. |
| [Excerpts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) | Searches a site |

You might have high hopes that the Excerpts searches in all posts but its details reveals for some of its parameters:

> q - a free form text parameter, will match all question properties based on an undocumented algorithm.
> body - text which must appear in returned questions' bodies.

So that is also limited to only questions.

Beyond that there are the following [site search options](https://stackapps.com/help/searching) that are lacking from the API:

- code
- score
- created
- lastacive
- inbookmarks
- intags
- hasaccepted
- hascode
- duplicate
- locked
- url
- deleted

**tl;dr:** The API only searches in Questions where the site search takes both Questions and Answers into their scope. There only is a small subset of search options available in the API.